# neo4j 2.1.5 with bulbs

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, bulbs

How can I connect bulbs with neo4j 2.1.5. I have followed the following steps but it doesnt help.

- Downloaded and unzipped neo4j 2.1.5.
- Downloaded and unzipped neo4j gremlin plugin 2.1.5.
- Copied all the jars from gremlin plugin to $NEO4J_HOME/plugins/gremlin-plugin
- Modified neo4j-server.properties to add this:

  `org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=com.thinkaurelius.neo4j.plugins=/tp`
- Restarted neo4j

  `bin/neo4j start`
- The extension doesnt show up

  `root@scspn0018050001:~# curl localhost:7474/db/data/
  {
    "extensions" : {
    },
    "node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node",
    "node_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node",
    "relationship_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship",
    "extensions_info" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext",
    "relationship_types" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
    "batch" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch",
    "cypher" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
    "indexes" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index",
    "constraints" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/constraint",
    "transaction" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction",
    "node_labels" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/labels",
    "neo4j_version" : "2.1.5"
  }`
- However this executes fine

  `root@scspn0018050001:~# curl http://localhost:7474/tp/gremlin/execute
  {"success":true}`
- Now, This is how my bulbs script look:

  `from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph,Config, NEO4J_URI
  config = Config('http://localhost:7474/db/data')
  graph = Graph(config)
  james = graph.vertices.create(name="James")`
- However I get the following error on executing the bulbs script

`root@scspn0018050001:~/neuro/src# python bulbsTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bulbsTest.py", line 4, in <module>
    james = graph.vertices.create(name="James")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/element.py", line 565, in create
    resp = self.client.create_vertex(data, keys=_keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 424, in create_vertex
    return self.create_indexed_vertex(data, index_name, keys=keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 1054, in create_indexed_vertex
    return self.gremlin(script,params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 384, in gremlin
    return self.request.post(path, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rest.py", line 131, in post
    return self.request(POST, path, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rest.py", line 186, in request
    return self.response_class(http_resp, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 217, in __init__
    self.handle_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 249, in handle_response
    response_handler(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bulbs/rest.py", line 39, in not_found
    raise LookupError(http_resp)
LookupError: ({'status': '404', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '752', 'server': 'Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)'}, '{\n  "message" : "No such ServerPlugin: \\"GremlinPlugin\\"",\n  "exception" : "PluginLookupException",\n  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLookupException",\n  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.extension(PluginManager.java:115)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:156)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)" ]\n}')`

Any help is appreciated.